# difference between Tokenization and Segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, terminology, text-segmentation

What is the difference between Tokenization and Segmentation in NLP. I searched about them but I didn't really find any differences
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: All tokenization is segmentation, but not all segmentation is tokenization. 
Long Answer: 
While segmentation is a more generic concept of splitting the input text, tokenization is a type of segmentation and it is carried out based on a well defined criteria.
For example - in a hypothetical scenario if all your input sentences are compound sentences of two sub-sentences, then splitting them into two independent sentences can be termed as segmentation (but not tokenization).
 Tokenization is a form of segmentation which is performed on the basis of a semantic criteria or using a token dictionary - e.g. a word or sub-word tokenization, mainly with an intention of assigning them token ids for downstream processing.

Comment: could you please give me a real world example for more clarification

Comment: Breaking your text corpus into sentences is segmentation, but not tokenization. Using sub-words of a sentence for generating token ids as input to a transformer model is tokenization (hence also segmentation)